# Open file in editor from browser, on Mac

Tags: macos, ide, protocols

I'd like to have a link which allows me to open a file in my favorite IDE. Textmate registeres it's own protocol `txmt://open/?url=file://%file&line=%line` and it works fine, but I can't find out how to open the file in some other application (for example NetBeans).

This probably requires registering some protocols and setting my browser - I'd like to register it on Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be difficult to register a system-wide URL handler for a protocol you design.  In your handler you can send the file on to your IDE.  The handler can be Cocoa based or applescript.

For a Cocoa solution, see [this post](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToRegisterURLHandler).  For a real world Cocoa example, you can look at [bwana](http://bruji.com/bwana/).

For an applescript solution, see [this post](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001154.html) or [this post](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/index.html) for a start.

Answer (score 1):

Try using http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/

Comment: Thanks, that is both nice and handy, but as far as I see it can't create new protocols.

Comment: … and for some reason, it's does not allow me to register the protocol to console files. This is unfortunate since Netbeans does not support passing arguments via url and therefor does not open the file at all. I need a “proxy“ file to format the arguments for executing IDE (either the shell or C application I can create, but not link to the protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I recently have been working in rails and error pages was set by default to open with txmt, to fix that I get with this idea.

1. download this wonderful tool https://github.com/johnste/finicky this is able to open certain pages in different browsers or rewrite domains for example.
2. Edith the config, so we're going to rewrite `txmt` format to `vscode` format

```
module.exports = {
  rewrite: [
    {
      match: /^txmt:\/\/open\?url=file:\/\/(.*)/,
      url: ({ urlString }) => {
        const newPath =  urlString
          .replace("txmt://open?url=file://", "vscode://file/") 
          .replace("&line=", ":")
          .replace("&column=", ":")

        finicky.log(newPath)
        return newPath
      }
    },
  ],
  handlers: [
    {
      match: /^vscode:\/\/(.*)/,
      browser: "Visual Studio Code"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. now we need to link any `txmt:` to finicky app, so, we do this in terminal:

```
# install duti https://github.com/moretension/duti/
brew install duti
# then associate the protocol
duti -s net.kassett.finicky txmt
```

4. restart the app